# Weblogic classpath

Tags: java, weblogic, classpath, weblogic8.x

I'm trying to find out what .jar files i have in the webglogic class path. I'm having an issue with logger, some one asked me to check duplicate log4j.jar files in the class path.

```
We Use         

 - Weblogic 8.1  

 - Java 1.4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution.

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```